# not showing content of tablayout in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I using tablayout in fragment but when transation as from Fragment 1 to Fragment2 and back to Fragment1,content of tablayout is not show...

Like the gif below:

[Gif](http://uupload.ir/files/j03h_untitled-1.gif)

fragment tab:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_chat);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_chat);


    Activity_Main.img_home.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
    Activity_Main.img_chat.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_chat));
    Activity_Main.img_setting.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.setting));


    AdapterTab_Chat adapterTab_chat = new AdapterTab_Chat(mcontex.getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterTab_chat);

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mcontex = (FragmentActivity) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

how fix it ???

Comment: show your code what your are trying

Comment: Based on what you shared, I'd say try "Alt + F4"

Comment: post your code here for tab layout fragment class quickly

Comment: @2Dee can you explain your answer a bit more ?

Comment: @quicklearner sure thing: if you forget to share your code while writing your question despite all the reminders when you sign up **and** when you write a question, the only suggestion that remains is have you quit the application and leave the premises.

Comment: @2Dee I thought we are here to help people who are new to programming especially , atleast he tried , Its not good to point out mistakes which is not a solution my dear ,

Comment: @Ali I added an answer , please let me know if it works or not for you

Comment: You didnt even asked him to add code or anythinhg like that, Than just saying'ALT + F4' , You way is pretty lame , I wont argue anymore over this , Bye

Answer (score 0):

create FragmentManager again

```
......
     FragmentManager fragmnetManager=mcontex.getSupportFragmentManager();
    AdapterTab_Chat adapterTab_chat = new   AdapterTab_Chat(fragmnetManager);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapterTab_chat);

viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        fragmnetManager=mcontex.getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }....
```

also create new fragmentManager for fragment in position =>CurrentItem(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

`getChildFragmentManager()` to its constructor

```
AdapterTab_Chat adapterTab_chat = new AdapterTab_Chat(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterTab_chat);
```

This will add these fragments to stack and will load again when you load the fragment with view pager